# Origin and use of the word "chachi"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, adjetivos

I often use the word *chachi* to say that something is good, or that I really like something:

> —¿Qué te parece si hoy vamos al cine?
>   —¡Chachi!

I would like to know the origin of the expression, but in the DLE I can only find that *[chachi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8RudNPJ)* redirects to *[chanchi](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8XeOJWr)*, and in that entry there is no clue about its origin. So what could be its origin?

About its use, I know that it is used in Andalusia, and both *chachi* and the variant *chanchi* are used in Castilla-La Mancha, both in Spain. Is it used elsewhere?